# Sveltekit - Form Action - fetch Post api using different port

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a front end local server using port 5173. I have a rest api backend on localhost but using different port, like port 3422. Is it possible to use Sveltekit Form Action if my front end running on 5173, but I want to send my request to 3422?

Debugging my form action gives me 500 because it uses http://localhost:5173/. What did I miss?

```js
export const actions = {
    default: async ({ request }) => {
        const formData = await request.formData()
        const param3 = formData.get('param3')
        const param4 = formData.get('param4')
        const param5 = formData.get('param5')
        
        const response = await fetch(import.meta.env.VITE_URL, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            attr3: param3,
            attr4: param4,
            attr5: 10
          })
        });
        const res = await response.json();
        return res;
    
      return {
        success: true,
      }
    }
}
```

Using it on html side simply: `<form method="POST">`

Comment: Why don't you just make the post to the URL with the port you want?  The `action` attribute is generic to form https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form and for your case should be the url with that other API.  The only thing you lose is the progressive enhancement.

Comment: appreciate it. Yes I know, but PE is a sveltekit feature and I would use that if possible.

Comment: Anyways, on rereading your question, you're doing that fetch on `import.meta.env.VITE_URL`.  Shouldn't it be `http://localhost:3422/`?

Comment: It's a simple environment variable, reading url from .env file.

Comment: I understand what the variable means and from what I can see your code is a relay.   Your problem is you're telling it to post to `import.meta.env.VITE_URL`, which is the wrong URL, but you want it to post to `http://localhost:3422/`.  Change `import.meta.env.VITE_URL` to `http://localhost:3422/`

Comment: Finally I used your first idea, providing the url in action because I didn't find a solution, but due to these port differences, I Got CORS error. lol